# Is the Redis Cache maxmemory-reserved setting exclusive to Azure?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

Inside Azure's Redis Cache Advanced Settings is the `maxmemory-reserved` setting, which [Microsoft documents as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-configure#maxmemory-policy-and-maxmemory-reserved):

> The maxmemory-reserved setting configures the amount of memory in MB
>   that is reserved for non-cache operations such as replication during
>   failover. It can also be used when you have a high fragmentation
>   ratio. Setting this value allows you to have a more consistent Redis
>   server experience when your load varies. This value should be set
>   higher for workloads which are write heavy. When memory is reserved
>   for such operations it is unavailable for storage of cached data.

I cannot find any documentation on [Redis.io](https://redis.io/documentation) about `maxmemory-reserved`, or within the server configuration file. The command `redis-cli config get maxmemory-reserved` also does not return anything, so I'm guessing  that this is a setting exclusive to Azure.

Is `maxmemory-reserved` a configurable setting on a Redis server that is not hosted by Azure? If not, is there a way to emulate `maxmemory-reserved`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a custom setting added to Redis by Microsoft.  You should be able to just use a different maxmemory setting in your Redis configuration file and it will accomplish more or less the same thing.